# how I can deal with missing instances of emotion of some sentences?

Tags: classification, weka, instances

can anyone help me .
I am using weka toolkit to classify emotions of speech
I have 6 sentences with different emotions, the task is to classify these emotions to the correct emotion.
the sentences are (S00,S01,S02,S03,S04,S05)
The emotions are (E00,E01,E02,E03)
but there are some sentences do not have emotion such as
s00 contains only (E01,E02) and missing E00 and E03
S05 contains only (E00,E01,E02) and missing E03

what I am going to do is divided my dataset to two sets (training set and test set) as described in tables :

[image]

as shown , the first experiment done on all dataset as training set except S00 which will be in test set and so on .

[image]

my question is :
missing emotions for sentences S00 and S05 make the prediction of classifier fails to recognize them correctly so what I can do in my case??because there are not enough instances of these emotions.

Comment: please ,any help

Comment: any help,please ?

Comment: any help,please ?